# Dynamically created elements not draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I have a simple block its element is dynamically added to DOM, I want the user to be able to create a block and it should be draggable using jsplumb library.

Unfortunately, now I can create element but their not draggable but if I add them manually to the dom, it's draggable.

Here is what I have so far

```
function addMovieButton() {

    var newMovieBlockButton = $("<div class='movie-button w'>Button New<div class='ep' action='begin'></div><div>");

}
```

Here is plumb.js

```
jsPlumb.ready(function () {

    // setup some defaults for jsPlumb.
    var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
        Endpoint: ["Dot", {radius: 5}],
        Connector:"StateMachine",
        HoverPaintStyle: {stroke: "#1e8151", strokeWidth: 2 },
        ConnectionOverlays: [
            [ "Arrow", {
                location: 1,
                id: "arrow",
                length: 14,
                foldback: 0.8
            } ],
            [ "Label", { label: "FOO", id: "label", cssClass: "aLabel" }]
        ],
        Container: "canvas"
    });

    instance.registerConnectionType("basic", { anchor:"Continuous", connector:"StateMachine" });

    window.jsp = instance;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var windows = jsPlumb.getSelector(".statemachine-demo .w");
    var windows_movie = jsPlumb.getSelector(".statemachine-demo .movie-block ");

    // bind a click listener to each connection; the connection is deleted. you could of course
    // just do this: jsPlumb.bind("click", jsPlumb.detach), but I wanted to make it clear what was
    // happening.
    instance.bind("click", function (c) {
        instance.deleteConnection(c);
    });

    // bind a connection listener. note that the parameter passed to this function contains more than
    // just the new connection - see the documentation for a full list of what is included in 'info'.
    // this listener sets the connection's internal
    // id as the label overlay's text.
    instance.bind("connection", function (info) {
        info.connection.getOverlay("label").setLabel(info.connection.id);
    });

    // bind a double click listener to "canvas"; add new node when this occurs.
    jsPlumb.on(canvas, "dblclick", function(e) {
      //  newNode(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    });

    //
    // initialise element as connection targets and source.
    //
    var initNode = function(el) {

        // initialise draggable elements.
        instance.draggable(el);

        instance.makeSource(el, {
            filter: ".ep",
            anchor: "Continuous",
            connectorStyle: { stroke: "#5c96bc", strokeWidth: 2, outlineStroke: "transparent", outlineWidth: 4 },
            connectionType:"basic",
            extract:{
                "action":"the-action"
            },
            maxConnections: 6,
            onMaxConnections: function (info, e) {
                alert("Maximum connections (" + info.maxConnections + ") reached");
            }
        });

        instance.makeTarget(el, {
            dropOptions: { hoverClass: "dragHover" },
            anchor: "Continuous",
            allowLoopback: true
        });

        // this is not part of the core demo functionality; it is a means for the Toolkit edition's wrapped
        // version of this demo to find out about new nodes being added.
        //
        instance.fire("jsPlumbDemoNodeAdded", el);
    };

    // suspend drawing and initialise.
    instance.batch(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
            initNode(windows[i], true);
            console.log(windows[i]);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < windows_movie.length; j++) {
            initNode(windows_movie[j], true);
            console.log(windows_movie[j]);
        }


    });

    jsPlumb.fire("jsPlumbDemoLoaded", instance);

});
```

Here is live demo [live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/)

Here is plunker [full source code](https://plnkr.co/edit/mjCxW2g0k5jHRfUT)

On the demo above just right click to add movie block for testing

Why does draggable not working for dynamically created elements?

Comment: You need to call `initNode()` again after adding the new elements to the DOM in order to initialise the `draggable()` library on them

Comment: Simple answer is event listeners can't be applied to elements that don't exist at the time the library function is initialized

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan where od I need to call initNode()??

Comment: Just after you append the new content

Comment: @charlietfl can answer that via code and little explanation? I am learning jsplumb thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ` var windows_movie = jsPlumb.getSelector(".statemachine-demo .movie-block ");
    initNode();` do you mean something like this?

Comment: Yes, although your function takes an argument, so you'll need to pass that too, whatever it should be.

Comment: Might also check the docs to see if there are methods that will reinitialize an instance when elements are added

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added as you suggested  but I am getting this error : `Uncaught TypeError: initNode is not a function` u can check it live https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/

Comment: The location you're calling the function from is not in scope of the `jsPlumb.ready()` handler

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please show me how it's done via answer?, I will really appreciate, thanks

Comment: If I could I would have, however it's not really as it's not entirely clear how all the JS and HTML fits together from the piecemeal example in the question. An MCVE would help a lot here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan here is full source code in plunker check out, https://plnkr.co/edit/mjCxW2g0k5jHRfUT

Comment: @charlietfl I am googling that, I can't find anything which can help, I am not giving up, :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan did you check it out?

Comment: If the method exists it would be in the library documentation of methods

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample [page](https://jsfiddle.net/greenwa/tLyuszfh/7/) I made a while ago when I first discovered 'jsplumb', it does exactly what you want so you might wanna use it or build on top of it.
Remember, indeed you should call the `draggable` method after the elements are added to the DOM, my example is so simple:

- it doesn't need the `jsplumb.fire`
- it doesn't need the `.ready` binding
- it doesn't need the 'batch' processing offered by jsplumb

so you get to avoid problems like the scope of ready and other I'm still trying to master.